# While loop in ssh command

Tags: linux, shell-script, shell, ssh

I have requirement to connect to remote machine and then get info and pipe to `while` loop.

```
ssh rao@172.168.1.123 "find ~/listfile/ -iname \"*log*\" |while read line; do cat $line; done"
```

The above commands is printing empty lines. I tried `find` itself to check command and it does works and list files.

```
ssh rao@172.168.1.123 "find ~/listfile/ -iname \"*log*\""
```

How do I see the content of files found?

Comment: I would have escaped the `$` in `cat $line` inside loop.

Comment: "_The above commands is printing empty lines._" it is likely also to be writing error messages about files not being found, as you're reading local file names based on a remote list

Answer (score 1):

You should use `find` alone if you are going to list files with matched name where you ssh in remote server and add only if files `-type f`.

```
ssh USER@HOST 'find ~/listfile/ -type f -iname "*log*" '
```

If you need to `cat` the content of the files found, use `find` with `cat` as follows.

```
ssh USER@HOST 'find ~/listfile/ -type f -iname "*log*" -exec cat {} +'
```

Your particular problem is that `$line` is expanded by the local shell as it's in double quotes. But any way, your apprach is a wrong way to loop over `find`'s results. See [Why is looping over find's output bad practice?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/321697) for details.

Comment: thanks for Quick answer.                                                                                                 Here my requirement is to find the files in remote machine and display the content of the files.

i.e the reason  i am using the CAT command